# Select from one table with a sub select concat rows for result

Tags: sql

I am looking for this result from a query from two tables. Looking to combine the results in the second table into one column. (TXM, TRD).  My brain is forgetting how to do this in MS Sql:

```
**FirstName LastName Training**
  Tom       Smith    TXM, TRD


**Table 1**
Id FirstName LastName
1  Tom        Smith

**Table 2**
UserId   Training
1        TXM
1        TRD
```

Thanks in advance for assisting.

Comment: But other parts of your anatomy remember!?!?

Comment: Anyway, it's called a JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `STUFF-FOR XML PATH('')` trick:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Training 
           FROM [Table 2] t2 
           WHERE t2.UserId = t1.Id 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Training
FROM [Table 1] t1
```

[`FOR XML PATH('')`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) creates a concatenated string from the result set, and [`STUFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) replaces the first two characters with nothing, removing the extra comma and space.

Don't forget the subquery has to be enclosed in a pair of parentheses.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Would have not thought there was a STUFF function.